# rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-11.04

Using rsync(ubuntu) and a DeltaCopy server on W2K3 to back up some of the data on the file server before I migrate from W2K3 to Ubuntu server. After it completed I ran a dry run just in case something had been missed or changed ... I got the following:

```
sudo rsync -az -n 198.3.9.25::Music /mnt/raid/music  
[sudo] password for daniel:
file has vanished: "?????\#267????" (in Music)
file has vanished: "????????" (in Music)
...
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1526) [generator=3.0.7]
```

I just want to make sure I'm reading it right, that somehow there are files on the receiving end that aren't on the sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are due to filesystem incompatibilities.  DeltaCopy (compiled with cygwin) is having trouble mapping some foreign language or reserved charaters in a few of your music files between the NTFS and EXT4.  Turn up the verbose level with -v and you'll probably spot them.  Then just rename them in windows to take out the problematic chars.

Comment: Took me a bit to find them ... had to make a log file :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also get this when ACL information or other filesystem data isn't transferable, such as between Windows and Linux for example.  In this case the file is usually transferred though.